# authentication with xamarin.android

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.android

So far I have spent quite a bit of time investigating various options with Xamarin for Visual Studio version 4.1.2 and Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.  When I try this sample: https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/LoginDemo

Here are the errors I'm getting for android:

```
1>100% ... 6793kb of 6793kb copied
1>:Deployment failed
1>Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
1>
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass90_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
1>The "InstallPackageAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
1>System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
1>
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass90_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>d__99.MoveNext()
1>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>d__98.MoveNext()
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
1>   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.InstallPackageAssemblies.Execute()
1>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
1>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
1>---> (Inner Exception #0) Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
1>
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass90_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>d__99.MoveNext()
1>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>d__98.MoveNext()<---
1>
1>Done building project "LoginPattern.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>Build FAILED.
1>
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Also, I have tried this sample: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/loginscreen/true

But have been unsuccessful.

Also, I tried modifying this to instead use a username and password:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/

But when I try to run it I'm getting this error:

```
1>100% ... 6146kb of 6146kb copied
1>:Deployment failed
1>Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
1>
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass90_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
1>The "InstallPackageAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
1>System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
1>
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass90_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>d__99.MoveNext()
1>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>d__98.MoveNext()
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
1>   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.InstallPackageAssemblies.Execute()
1>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
1>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
1>---> (Inner Exception #0) Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
1>
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass90_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>d__99.MoveNext()
1>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>d__98.MoveNext()<---
1>
1>Done building project "TuberEduMobile.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>Build FAILED.
1>
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Finally, I have also experimented with xamarin.xauth, based on this code: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth.git

But I get this error when I try to build it:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0115  'WebAuthenticatorActivity.Client.OnPageStarted(WebView, string, Graphics.Bitmap)': no suitable method found to override Xamarin.Auth.Android    C:\Projects\Xamarin.Auth\src\Xamarin.Auth.Android\WebAuthenticatorActivity.cs   165 Active
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

**UPDATE:**

Also, I have tried this sample:

https://github.com/jsauve/OAuthTwoDemo.XForms.git

But when I run it I get this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**UPDATE 2:**

So basically, my question is, does anybody know a way to get authentication working on Xamarin.Android?